# Issue in expert html2pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I have used expert html2pdf for pdf genratiion

- I have one table consisting the various row with background color
- after converting the html table to pdf it display space between table rows,
  when set zoom level of pdf to 100% .
- If i reduced the zoom level below 75% it not display any space
- Please check following screens

Screen 100%
http://prntscr.com/6o2019

Screen 75%
http://prntscr.com/6o20f2

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that lack of margins is related with rendering of PDF file by Adobe Reader and what scale algorithms Adobe Reader uses and has nothing to do with html2pdf library (and any other as well). Suppose that this behavior may be different in other readers, e.g try to open in Firefox build-in reader (it written in JavaScript) or other reader, so margins may disappear with other zoom or not disappear at all.

If it is I'm afraid it is impossible to somehow fix this behavior of the particular reader program. Try to ask about this issue Adobe Reader developers.

Or try to reimplement design of your table - e.g. to increase margins, etc.

Comment: Thank  you for reply . I have replaced the table structure with Div structure then also facing the same issue.